# Bluetooth Low Energy connection with special device

Tags: android, bluetooth, bluetooth-lowenergy

I'm writing an android app which is to connect a special BLE device, reading data feedback from the device. First I need to write a shake-hand code "234" to the device, and it will return a code, then start to feeding data. 
I've done with the iOS version, which is quite simple to implement, however the android version has so many problems. Hope you guys have any sample which can be used for me to understand how it works in whole process. Many thx.

Comment: I've seen [THIS](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/development/+/master/samples/BluetoothLeGatt), what I need is a simple process of sending code and looping reading.

Answer (score 0):

This is documentation from Android: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/connectivity/bluetooth-le.html
There is an example. Please use it as guide. Pretty simple example.

About your question. What Profile to you use?  You should know that BLE exchange data through the Service/Characteristic/Descriptor system. So on your device should be any Profile. Or your use any of standard?

Comment: My BLE part is based on the sample of official documentation, however its simplicity makes me feels harder to add stuffs. Thx anyway.